# how to group by every hour possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create a report that shows the number of blocks created in every hour in the current date.

case no blocks were created I need to display the hour and 0 next to it.

I must use access for this. I tried many things but the only code compiled was this one.

```
SELECT Hour(DateOfCreation) As Hour , Count(*) AS amount
FROM tblBlock
WHERE DateOfCreation = Date ()
GROUP BY Hour(DateOfCreation)
```

my code gives me the hours that blocks were created in, but I can't figure out how to add those hours the no blocks were created.

Comment: Options: 1) a dataset of all possible date/hour combinations joined to actual data, 2) UNION a dummy record for each hour, 3) DCount() expression in 24 textboxes. I have used the last for a by month output. Fairly common topic. Review https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3844021/Reporting-whats-not-there.htm

Comment: In MS Access, this is probably best done at the application layer.

Comment: @June7 can you give me an example of the second option?

Comment: See first 3 examples in the referenced link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small query to give you 10 numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Save this as *Ten* and use it twice in another query:

```
SELECT TimeSerial([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10,0,0) AS [Hour]
FROM Ten AS Ten_0, Ten AS Ten_1
WHERE ((([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10)<24))
ORDER BY TimeSerial([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10,0,0);
```

To return the integer hour (to match your query), use this variant:

```
SELECT [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10 AS [Hour]
FROM Ten AS Ten_0, Ten AS Ten_1
WHERE ((([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10)<24))
ORDER BY TimeSerial([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10,0,0);
```

Now, either modify this to include your original query, or use it in a third query where you create an outer join between the *Hour* of the query above and *Hour* of your original query. It could be like this:

```
SELECT HoursOneDay.Hour, YourQuery.Amount
FROM HoursOneDay 
LEFT JOIN YourQuery ON HoursOneDay.Hour = YourQuery.Hour;
```

The *Amount* field will be *Null* for those entries with no hours. Either apply *Nz*, or set the *Format* where you display the values.

Comment: can you help me with the modification of the query?

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on this code, "missing operator".

Comment: Then you probably have a typo or similar. Code is tested and works here.